# Getting error while applying PIVOT operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have to apply joins on few tables having some details of evaluation taken by users in form of Questions. Some evaluations have 10 questions while others may have 5 only. The answers to the questions needs to be displayed as columns instead of rows.
I have prepared the below query :

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#VALS') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #VALS
END
GO
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @VALS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING('QuestionText', 1, 100) AS Vals
INTO #VALS FROM Analytics.DimEvaluation
SELECT @VALS = COALESCE(@VALS+', ','') + '[' + VALS + ']' FROM #VALS
SET @SQL = 'SELECT top 10
Act.ActivityCode as [Region]
    ,Act.ActivityType AS [Activity Type]
    ,Act.ActivityCode AS [Activity Code]
    ,Act.ActivityName AS [Activity Name]
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME, Act.StartDate, 102) AS [Activity Start Time]
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME, Act.EndDate, 102) AS [Activity End Time]
    ,DimLoc.FacilityName AS [Facility]
    ,DimLoc.FacilityCity + '''' + DimLoc.FacilityCountry AS [Facility City, Facility Country]
    ,Act.EstimatedCreditHours AS [Estimated Credit Hours]
    ,REPLACE(Emp.ImportKey, '','', '''') AS [User Global ID]
    ,(SELECT NoteText FROM PERSON WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PersonPk = emp.SourceID) AS [Local Employee Number]
    ,Emp.FirstName AS [First Name]
    ,Emp.LastName AS [Last Name]
    ,Emp.FirstName + '''' + Emp.LastName AS [User Full Name]
    ,Emp.Email AS [User Email]
    ,'+@VALS+' 
    AS [STTEST]
FROM Analytics.DimActivity AS Act WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Analytics.FactActivityLocation factResLoc WITH (NOLOCK) ON factResLoc.DimActivityId = Act.DimActivityId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Analytics.DimLocation DimLoc WITH (NOLOCK) ON DimLoc.DimLocationId = factResLoc.DimLocationId
INNER JOIN Analytics.FactActivityAttempt FACT WITH (NOLOCK) ON fact.DimActivityId = Act.DimActivityId
INNER JOIN Analytics.DimEmployee Emp WITH (NOLOCK) ON Emp.DimEmployeeID = fact.Dimemployeeid
inner join Analytics.FactEvaluation FactEval WITH (NOLOCK) on FactEval.DimActivityId = Act.DimActivityId
inner join Analytics.DimEvaluation DimEval WITH (NOLOCK) on FactEval.DimEvaluationId = DimEval.DimEvaluationId
PIVOT(MIN([Answer]) FOR [QuestionText] IN ('+@VALS+')) PIV'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```

But when executing, I am getting below error:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
SELECT top 10 Act.ActivityCode as [Region]
         ,Act.ActivityType AS [Activity Type]
         ,Act.ActivityCode AS [Activity Code]
         ,Act.ActivityName AS [Activity Name]
         ,CONVERT(DATETIME, Act.StartDate, 102) AS [Activity Start Time]
         ,CONVERT(DATETIME, Act.EndDate, 102) AS [Activity End Time]
         ,DimLoc.FacilityName AS [Facility]
         ,DimLoc.FacilityCity + '' + DimLoc.FacilityCountry AS [Facility City, Facility Country]
          ,Act.EstimatedCreditHours AS [Estimated Credit Hours]
         ,REPLACE(Emp.ImportKey, ',', '') AS [User Global ID]
         ,(SELECT NoteText FROM PERSON WITH (NOLOCK)     WHERE PersonPk = emp.SourceID) AS [Local Employee Number]
         ,Emp.FirstName AS [First Name]
         ,Emp.LastName AS [Last Name]
         ,Emp.FirstName + '' + Emp.LastName AS [User Full Name]
         ,Emp.Email AS [User Email]
         ,[QuestionText] 
         AS [STTEST]
FROM Analytics.DimActivity AS Act WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Analytics.FactActivityLocation factResLoc WITH (NOLOCK) ON factResLoc.DimActivityId = Act.DimActivityId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Analytics.DimLocation DimLoc WITH (NOLOCK) ON DimLoc.DimLocationId = factResLoc.DimLocationId
INNER JOIN Analytics.FactActivityAttempt FACT WITH (NOLOCK) ON fact.DimActivityId = Act.DimActivityId
INNER JOIN Analytics.DimEmployee Emp WITH (NOLOCK) ON Emp.DimEmployeeID = fact.Dimemployeeid
inner join Analytics.FactEvaluation FactEval WITH (NOLOCK) on FactEval.DimActivityId = Act.DimActivityId
inner join Analytics.DimEvaluation DimEval WITH (NOLOCK) on FactEval.DimEvaluationId = DimEval.DimEvaluationId
PIVOT(MIN([Answer]) FOR [QuestionText] IN ([QuestionText])) PIV
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
The column name "QuestionText" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
The column 'DimActivityId' was specified multiple times for 'PIV'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "Act.ActivityCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "Act.ActivityType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "Act.ActivityCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The multi-part identifier "Act.ActivityName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "Act.StartDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "Act.EndDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The multi-part identifier "DimLoc.FacilityName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
The multi-part identifier "DimLoc.FacilityCity" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
The multi-part identifier "DimLoc.FacilityCountry" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
The multi-part identifier "Act.EstimatedCreditHours" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "Emp.ImportKey" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "emp.SourceID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "Emp.FirstName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The multi-part identifier "Emp.LastName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The multi-part identifier "Emp.FirstName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The multi-part identifier "Emp.LastName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The multi-part identifier "Emp.Email" could not be bound.
```

Need help in identifying the error and resolving it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Stop splattering `NOLOCK` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere), it's not a "go-faster" switch, it's a "give incorrect results" switch. That won't fix your issue though, which is that you need to subquery because you cannot `JOIN` and `PIVOT` in the same level of the query

Answer (score 0):

You definetly want distinct values from `QuestionText` column, not its name

```
..
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(QuestionText, 1, 100) AS Vals
INTO #VALS 
FROM Analytics.DimEvaluation;
..
```

BTW `NOLOCK`, hope you know what are you doing. You can get inconsistent  results if any update are runninng at the time.

Comment: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 529
The column 'DimActivityId' was specified multiple times for 'PIV'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "Act.ActivityCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "Act.ActivityType" could not be bound.

Comment: Try debug it step by step, each subquery. A query 529+ lines long could be too big piece of code to debug.